# Help upgrading RHEL 5.1 to CentOS 5.1

Tags: centos, yum, rhel5

I'm trying to follow the steps from the [MigrationGuide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide) (modified to reflect the fact I'm dealing with non-current versions) to migrate from RHEL 5.1 to CentOS 5.1. I used the following commands:

```
# rpm -e --nodeps redhat-release-notes redhat-release yum-rhn-plugin redhat-logos
# rpm -ivh http://vault.centos.org/5.1/os/x86_64/CentOS/centos-release-5-1.0.el5.centos.1.x86_64.rpm http://vault.centos.org/5.1/os/x86_64/CentOS/centos-release-notes-5.1.0-2.x86_64.rpm
# yum update
```

This fails on the `yum update` step with an error claiming there's a conflict between e2fsprogs and the kernel. I've included a more detailed error below.

```
# yum -d7 upgrade kernel
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Running "config" handler for "installonlyn" plugin
Yum Version: 3.0.1
COMMAND: yum -d7 
Installroot: /
Ext Commands:

   kernel
Setting up Upgrade Process
Setting up repositories
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Setting up Package Sacks
Reading Local RPMDB
Building updates object
Resolving Dependencies
1248192166.57
--> Populating transaction set with selected packages. Please wait.
Member: kernel.x86_64 0-2.6.18-128.2.1.el5 - u
kernel - 2.6.18-128.2.1.el5.x86_64 converted to install
Adding Package kernel - 2.6.18-128.2.1.el5.x86_64 in mode i
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.18-128.2.1.el5 set to be installed
--> Running transaction check
# of Deps = 1

Dep Number: 1/1

--> Processing Conflict: kernel conflicts e2fsprogs < 1.37-4
TSINFO: Updating e2fsprogs - 1.39-20.el5.x86_64 to resolve conflict.
miss = 0
conf = 0
CheckDeps = 1
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
---> Loop Number: 2
Restarting Loop
--> Populating transaction set with selected packages. Please wait.
Member: kernel.x86_64 0-2.6.18-128.2.1.el5 - i
Member: e2fsprogs.x86_64 0-1.39-20.el5 - u
Adding Package e2fsprogs - 1.39-20.el5.x86_64 in mode u
---> Package e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.39-20.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
# of Deps = 3

Dep Number: 1/3

--> Processing Conflict: kernel conflicts e2fsprogs < 1.37-4
Error: No Package Matching kernel.x86_64
```

Comment: Just a question: are you updating from the x86_64 version of RHEL 5.1?

Comment: Yes. I almost upgraded x86_64 to i386 but caught my mistake just in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the 32 bit version (i386,i586,i686) of e2fsprogs exists in your system and remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: On a similar note, I found this bug report: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=1962

Answer (score 1):

As HD says, there's a known bug in older versions of yum that if there is 2 or more conflicts ona  single package yum will fix the first one and then bail on the second (here conflicts for both .i?86 and .x86_64 count one each).

You can either get a beta version of yum for 5.4, or remove one of the arches ... or manually update e2fsprogs as well (so there is no conflict).